# Notification count in menu item using backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

We are using backbone as our client side MVC and we need to implement a menu view.
Its a basic horizontal

with

as individual menu items. 
The feature we need is that it should be dynamic, like if we have an `Items` link, and a new `Item` is added, it should be shown in red notification circle over the link.

Should the `<ul>` be a view of collection, which maintains the individual `<li>`. The `<li>` in turn is a view of the model/collection. ( For `Items` it will be `ItemCollection`, so it can get the count to be shown on notification ).

Im not sure how the count will be update and the menu refreshed when an `Item` is added to the `Items` collection.

Open to other suggestions and alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the initialize method of your view you need to bind to the reset, add and remove events of your collection to call the render method, like this

```
App.Views.MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.collection.bind('reset', this.render, this);
        this.collection.bind('add', this.render, this);
        this.collection.bind('remove', this.render, this);
    }
```

Then in your render method update the view using this.collection.length